# Get selected checkbox values from parent and child in angular

Tags: angular, checkbox, selected

I am trying to generate a new array from this data and show only selected checkbox values from parent as well child.

this.data.ParentChildchecklist = [
{
id: 1,value: 'Elenor Anderson',isSelected: false,isClosed:false,
childList: [
{
id: 1,parent_id: 1,value: 'child 1',isSelected: false
},
{
id: 2,parent_id: 1,value: 'child 2',isSelected: false
}
]
},
{
id: 2,value: 'Caden Kunze',isSelected: false,isClosed:false,childList: [
{
id: 1,parent_id: 1,value: 'child 1',isSelected: false
},
{
id: 2,parent_id: 1,value: 'child 2',isSelected: false
}
]
},
{
id: 3,value: 'Ms. Hortense Zulauf',isSelected: false,isClosed:false,
childList: [
{
id: 1,parent_id: 1,value: 'child 1',isSelected: false
},
{
id: 2,parent_id: 1,value: 'child 2',isSelected: false
}
]
}
];

Tried this code to filter the selected list from parent and child to push to new List but its not working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hfvrqa?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in your example

this line maybe should be removed

```
this.checkedList.ParentChildchecklist.push(
    obj.ParentChildchecklist[i].childList[j]
);
```

because `this.checkedList.ParentChildchecklist` does not exist